# Selection Operators for Genetic Algorithms

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

Does anybody know of a definitive list of selection operators for Genetic Algorithms ? 
I am looking for methods other than the usual "*Roulette Wheel*" or "*Tournament*" selection methods.

Most lists/literature I have seen use the prase "and other lesser used methods" without saying what they are.

Thanks,

NWS.

Comment: disruptive selection : http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18263031

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three most commonly used selection methods are proportional ("roulette wheel"), tournament, and ranking. There's no definitive list of these because, as the previous responder noted, new schemes and variants are proposed all of the time (but don't necessarily catch on). Also keep in mind that each of these can have elitist variants, where the best individual is guaranteed to be selected, that generation gaps are often used, and that proportional selection often uses some form of scaling.

For one attempt at a general classification system of selection schemes, see:

Thomas Bäck and Frank Hoffmeister. (1991). Extended selection mechanisms in genetic algorithms. In Belew and Booker (eds.), Proceedings of the Fourth International Conference on Genetic Algorithms, pp. 92-99. Morgan Kaufmann.

Hope that helps.

-Ted Belding

www.beldingconsulting.com

Comment: Excellent ! I will research this as soon as i get some spare time ;)

Answer (score 4):

"and other lesser used methods" usually means "whatever someone else came up with and used only once or twice" :)

That said, some other relatively common selection operators are

- *Top Percent*: randomly choose from the top N percent
- *Best*: choose the best
- *Random*: just random
- *Truncation Selection*: [see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_selection)
- *Boltzmann selection*: where selection pressure increases...

and maybe 1 or 2 others.